# Android: Changing Inclination of phone returns me to the main.xml view

Tags: android, layout

I've been developing an Android App and I have encountered a small problem when putting my phone horizontally.

At the moment I have two views: The main one (main.xml) and a login view (login.xml). When I turn my phone while being in the login.xml view, it returns me to the main.xml view. The same thing happens if the phone is in horizontal position + login.xml and I turn it again (goes back to main.xml).

It sees that the "OnCreate" is executed each time, here is the code for the app:

```
    public class AppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageButton bout= null;
    bout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    bout.setOnClickListener(boutlisten);

}

private OnClickListener boutlisten = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.login);


        }
    };
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new Activity which have `setContentView(R.layout.login);` and start Activity.

Like,

```
   public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

}

}
```

- [See here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

***Addendum:*** This is the code to launch the activity declared above. One should also declare the activity in the manifest file

```
     private OnClickListener boutlisten = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    };
```

Comment: MMM so as I suspected i'm doing it wrong. I'll try this and accept the answer asap. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Also, as u must already be aware of..don't forget to declare the new activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
```

Alternatively, you may also force your activity to run just vertically. Just add this to your Main activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" ...../>
```